# how to put value from arraylist<map<String,String>> to a class

Tags: android

I'm beginner, I want to ask somethings about android. I have a variable of `String<map<String,String>>` like this:

```
[{tt=id:1}{tt=name:Jone}{tt=email:Jone@gmail.com}]
```

and I have a class like this:

```
public Class User{
    int id;
    String name;
    String email;

    public void setId(String id){
        this.id=id;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }
    public void setemail(String email){
        this.email=email;
    }
    public User(int id,String name,String email){
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.email=email;
    }
}
```

now I want to create a object of this class with data is getted from the variable above, but I don't know how to do, please help me! thank.

Comment: you have to make a Arraylist of your class...

Comment: String<map<String,String>>  this is ArrayList not String

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Gson or Jackson libriries to convert a JSON string to an equivalent Java object:

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload

Comment: a few links may be way outside the OP's comfort zone.